# jQuery $('.someClass').click(function(){}) only applies to elements that are currently present?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am constantly adding new points to a graph and I want all of them to have the same click function. But it seems like when I run

```
$('.someClass').click(function(){})
```

it only applies to elements that currently have someClass. If I add a new someClass element, it does not have the click listener.

How do I get around this? Must I run click function every time I add an element?

Comment: when you dynamically add elements to the DOM you have to re-bind then with events and an automatic/easy/etc way of doing it is to use `.live` as specified by many answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.someClass').live('click', function(){});
```

Or even better consider [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$('.someClass').live('click',function(){
  // Handle here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you have not registered the new objects with the `jQuery` code.
You can try run the `javascript` code above after you add the points.

If it was jsf, for example:

```
<h:commandButton value="Add Point>
  <f:ajax onevent="registerSomeClassObject"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also use jquery `bind` method.